# What's the best approach to cutting dry walnut with a hand saw?

Tags: hardwood

so, it may seem impractical to cut really hard woods with hand tools, but i know it can be done with the right tools...i generally assume for really tough woods and cross-cuts it's best to use a bow saw. I'm cutting through some thick walnut vertically, and the bow saw has already gone half way through, but the blade is now damaged and it's proving a total hassel to try and knock out the pin that holds the blade in place, i've got it part of the way out with a hammer and knife but it doesn't appear like it was meant to take it out and replace (saw companies: why not just hold it in with a normal phillips head screw?!)

before i go out and buy anything else, i just wanted to ask you all, if you hypothetically wanted to cut through dry walnut with a hand saw, what would you do? the normal hand saw i have seems to work but it cuts so damn slow and i know it's gonna ruin the blades like the other one.

Comment: How thick are we talking? And just to confirm, this is a cross cut (against the grain), and not a rip cut (with the grain) you're talking about, right?

Comment: yes, its cross cut. I put it on it's side because it's 11 inches wide, so im cutting down through that, it's 2 and half inches thick this way. I put it on it's side because i couldn't get blade to bite into the wood for the initial groove. I don't need the cut to be perfectly straight because this is going to be the end of a table, and i really don't want to waste the wood because it's a great table top and i got it for free.

Comment: In the future, a good way to get the blade to bite is to score a knife line, and then widen that knife line with a chisel. That gives a small groove for the blade to ride and prevents it from wandering.

Comment: How is the walnut supported? It sounds like it is pinching together as you cut, causing the blade to bind. It would do this if you're supporting it on only two sawhorses or other supports. If you support it in four places, both boards that will result from a cut will be supported throughout and after the cut.

Comment: yeah, i was just holding it with my hand with two cinderblocks on the end close to where im cutting (lol), i need to find a way to keep it stable. I'm making a table so i can bow making (bow and arrow bow)...wood working is fun right?!

Comment: I think this is your biggest problem. No saw is going to get through the wood if it isn't supported; any blade will bind when the unsupported wood sags and pinches it. I bet if you support it correctly, you'll have a much easier time cutting through the wood. This blade might be toast, but just about any cross cut blade should work fine.

Comment: One thought, though: Depending on your bow saw, you might run into another problem. Is it deep enough to cut all the way through the wood? If not, you might want to look at buying a simple hand saw instead, if you have to replace the blade anyway.

Comment: Walnut is not even remotely a "really hard wood" - it cuts quite easily.

Comment: If I'm picturing this right, the "pin" in your blade likely isn't made to be removed, rather the tension on the blade needs to be decreased and then the blade can be removed.  the pin acts as a T and provides the support for the tensioner.

Comment: @thinksinbinary it was down voted because it is more of a rant than a question.  SE is meant for more narrowly scoped questions that have concrete answers.  Your question would likely get positive votes if it was broken down into questions like "How do I remove the blade from my saw" and "What are some techniques for efficient hand sawing with a bow saw"

Comment: Here's my take on why this got downvotes (worth remember it's the *Question* that got downvoted, not you, it's not personal no matter how it feels). It's because of all the things respondents would like to know to provide an Answer but weren't included in the Question. You mention the wood is walnut and thick, but how thick? And what do you mean by cutting vertically? It's very ambiguous, but a photo would have clarified everything. Then the bow saw you were using is an unknown [photo] then again the "normal hand saw" [photo]. See what I mean? Contd. in my next Comment.

Comment: So assuming this is a thick piece of dry walnut like you think it is it should cut easily with the right hand saw. As @Ecnerwal referred to in a previous Comment, walnut is not a particularly hard wood, in fact it's noted for being easily worked! So a sharp saw of the right type should be able to motor through it, accomplishing the cut in under 10 minutes, 5 minutes or less with a really good saw — some cross-cut saws are reported to be able to go through 1" per 10 strokes in some common hardwoods to give you an idea of how fast a hand saw can cut!

Comment: Spend less time in the comments and more time taking and posting pictures, and editing this question to be only one of your questions, and posting the other question (with appropriate pictures) as a separate question. I have refrained from downvoting, but starting with a fallacy (walnut is really hard? noooope!) does not help your question. If you've only ever worked with balsa and basswood I suppose it might seem that way, but it is indeed widely loved for being so easy to work. I suspect that your "vertical cut" is a rip, not a crosscut, but pictures would clear up what you actually mean.

Comment: @thinksinbinary your question is vague because you did not provide dimensions or photos, and "cutting through some thick walnut vertically" does not mean anything to us, so it would be helpful to go back and update the question to reflect your clarifications from the comments. Regarding comments about tolerance and downvotes, everyone is providing constructive suggestions and nobody intended to offend you. As has already been suggested, I recommend adding photos and splitting this into multiple questions with better details, including dimensions and type of blade.

Comment: the funny thing is that people got offended that i expressed dissaproval of the downvotes...lol, funny, right?

Answer (score 2):

I'll just answer the title, as the question is in dire need of edits to be either a good question or answerable.

1. Use a sharp saw. This is a fundamental requirement for using hand saws.
2. Support the wood properly, so that it neither pinches and binds the saw nor splinters at the end of the cut.
3. Use the proper type of saw for the direction you are cutting. Rip tooth when parallel to the grain or nearly so, crosscut when 90 degrees to the grain or nearly so. Some saws have combination teeth that work equally well (or equally poorly) in either direction.
4. Arrange the work and support at a comfortable height - depending on the type of saw you are using and the scale of the cut, heavy work is often more easily accomplished at a lower height than "standard" sawhorses and benches are set (current sawhorses are geared towards power saw use.) A good sawbench for Western/American pattern handsaws is typically close to knee high. A traditional Japanese sawbench (IIRC) is an angled beam that you can pick a comfortable spot to work on, and the work is marked on all sides and turned as you saw it such that you never cut the beam. Being too low or too high makes sawing awkward, and awkward is difficult.

Comment: Well done cutting through the chaff +1. Re. the Japanese sawbench, I think you're thinking of their planing beams. All the Japanese sawhorses I've seen are horizontal and low to the ground.

Comment: You are probably right. I use knockoff Japanese saws (as well as Western styles), but am not really a dedicated follower of the whole process, though I'm willing to borrow tools and techniques from anywhere that seems like it will help my woodworking.